# Oracle DB trigger-based synchronization error in history store table type 0?

Tags: oracle, types, triggers, data-synchronization

We are doing a *trigger-based* synch with DB Convert studio tool from Oracle as a source. This method creates triggers on each table and a `history_store` table.

But, the software that uses the source oracle DB gives the following error and refuses to work:

> Unknown type (table: history_store, column: pk_date_dest, type: 0)

The `pk_date_dest` column is initialized as `"pk_date_dest" NVARCHAR2(400) NOT NULL`. What might be the reason for this *type 0*?

Comment: Best guess with what you've provided is that something in the app is trying to validate the database schema content against an ORM-defined schema in the code, and it doesn't know how to map the `NVARCHAR2` data type. Even if it could, I'm guessing that it might then have a problem with all of the new tables in the schema. Either way, the schema validation fails and the app doesn't start.

Comment: Seems logical. But Oracle should have no problems with nvarchar2. Really strange... Our whole app will be unusable if we don't fix this somehow. Any pointers or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's Oracle that is having the problem with NVARCHAR2: it's the application code. That said, this is only a best guess, based on experience. You'd have to confirm by going through your application code.

Comment: It is the application, yes. Unfortunately we can't go through the code as it is a vendor application. Anyway, changing the data type to VARCHAR2 seemed to fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed manually the `NVARCHAR2` data type of the columns to `VARCHAR2` and the error stopped appearing. Quite strange to be honest, as there are `NVARCHAR2` data types in other tables that are native to the database, but... at least that fixed it.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY ("pk_date_dest" VARCHAR2(400));
```